# java construct method overload with multi match

Tags: java, overloading, construct

Refer to the code below:

```
public class ExpandableTextView extends TextView {

    public ExpandableTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, null);
    }

    public ExpandableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, null);
    }

    public ExpandableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, Runnable runnable) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ExpandableTextView);
        this.trimLength = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.ExpandableTextView_trimLength, DEFAULT_TRIM_LENGTH);
        typedArray.recycle();

        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                trim = !trim;
                setText();
                requestFocusFromTouch();
            }
        });
    }

    public ExpandableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, Activity activity) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ExpandableTextView);
        this.trimLength = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.ExpandableTextView_trimLength, DEFAULT_TRIM_LENGTH);
        typedArray.recycle();

        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                trim = !trim;
                setText();
                requestFocusFromTouch();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

method like this(context, null, null); could refer to two other constructor methods, is there any way that i can specify which one it refers to rather than changing the signature or the "null"?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just cast the `null` into the signature type!

```
    new ExpandableTextView(context, (AttributeSet)null, (Runnable)null)
```

Comment: TIL you can cast `null`.

Comment: @ILikeTau Because of that we can even do crazy things like `((Math)null).max(1, 2);`

Comment: So if I do something like `System.out.println((ClassA)(null))` it will call `ClassA`'s `toString()` but `System.out.println((ClassB)(null))` will call `ClassB`'s `toString()`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should not work as Compiler will throw error mentioning ambiguous method. Because Java will always try to use the most specific applicable version of a method that's available (see JLS §15.12.2). And `null` is a valid value for the types Context, AttributeSet and Runnable. Therefore all 3 version are applicable.